# Complexes in stable categories

Tags: ct.category-theory, infinity-categories

Generalizing from 1-category theory, there's a simple definition of a "naive complex" in a stable $\infty$-category. Considering bounded positive graded chain complexes, they are a sequence of maps

$$ A_n \xrightarrow{d_n} A_{n-1} \xrightarrow{d_{n-1}} \ldots \xrightarrow{d_1} A_0 $$

with the property that $d_k d_{k+1} \simeq 0$. If I've not made any errors, then at first blush they seem to have a reasonable theory, along with a nice "realization" given by iteratively taking homotopy cofibers:

$$ |A| = \mathrm{cofib}(\mathrm{cofib}(\ldots) \to A_0) $$

that parallels taking the total complex of a bicomplex. This realization can also be given by the colimit of the diagram

$$ A_n \rightrightarrows^{d_n}_0 A_{n-1} \rightrightarrows \ldots  \rightrightarrows^{d_1}_0 A_0$$

---

However, naive complexes don't seem to be studied. Instead, in Higher Algebra, Lurie proves a Dold-Kan correspondence stable $\infty$-category asserting equivalences between the categories of:

- Simplicial objects
- Filtered objects (i.e. arbitrary $\mathbb{Z}_{\geq 0}$-indexed diagrams)
- upper-triangular array with zeroes along the diagonal, in which every square is a pushout

and it is this last sort of thing that Lurie calls a complex. (Specifically, a $\mathbb{Z}_{\geq 0}$-complex)

It is only when looking at the homotopy category does Lurie say anything about a correspondence between simplicial objects and naive complexes.

So my question is whether this is an oversight; i.e.

> Is the $\infty$-category of simplicial objects in a stable $\infty$-category equivalent to the $\infty$-category of (unbounded, positively graded) naive complexes?

and if the answer is no, what goes wrong?

Comment: I don’t think they are equivalent. When n=2 the obstruction for such a complex to arise from a little filtration is the Toda bracket of the three differentials. Another issue is that I don’t think your category of complexes will have hocolims.

Comment: Another issue is that I don’t see how you’re able to take those iterated cofibers (or equivalently, to form that diagram to take the colimit) without remembering witnesses for those nullhomotopies (and compatibilities between them).

Comment: The homotopies d_k d_{k+1}≃0 must themselves fit into a higher coherence data.  If you add this data, then you indeed get an equivalence of ∞-categories between chain complexes and simplicial objects.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Here is the problem with the notion of naive complex. Suppose we have a naive complex
$$ \require{AMScd} \begin{CD}
A @>f>> B @>g>> C @>h>> D \end{CD} $$
If we propose to compute the realization iteratively, the first step would be to produce the sequence
$$ \require{AMScd} \begin{CD}
\mathrm{cofib}(f) @>>> C @>h>> D \end{CD} $$
However, this need not be a naive complex! So everything falls apart.

A more elaborate explanation is to look at the big diagram of pushout squares one can construct from the complex:

$$ \require{AMScd} \begin{CD}
A  @>f>> B @>>> 0
\\ @VVV @VVV @VVV
\\ 0 @>>> \mathrm{cofib}(f) @>>> \Sigma A @>>> 0
\\  & & @VVV @VVV @VVV
\\  & & C @>>> \mathrm{cofib}(g) @>>> \mathrm{cofib}(\mathrm{cofib}(f) \to C)
\\ & & & & @VVV
\\ & & & & D
\end{CD} $$
There is no direct way to produce the expected map $\mathrm{cofib}(\mathrm{cofib}(f) \to C) \to D$. In fact, by the rightmost square, one can only possibly exist if $(\Sigma A \to D) \simeq 0$.

The map $\Sigma A \to D$ is the Toda bracket mentioned in the comments. ([wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Toda_bracket) [nlab](https://ncatlab.org/nlab/show/Toda+bracket))

---

We can give an explicit counterexample. In the $\infty$-category of chain complexes, suppose our naive complex is given by:

$$ \require{AMScd} \begin{CD}
0  @>>> 0 @>>> \mathbb{Z}/4 @>1>> \mathbb{Z}/4
\\ @VVV @VVV @VV4V @VVV
\\ \mathbb{Z} @>2>> \mathbb{Z}/4 @>2>> \mathbb{Z}/8 @>>> 0
\end{CD} $$

That this is a naive complex can be checked on the homology groups. This isn't a bicomplex as is, and the point is that it cannot be improved to become one! One can show that after replacing $A \xrightarrow{f} B$ with $\mathrm{cofib}(f)$, the diagram becomes

$$ \require{AMScd} \begin{CD}
\mathbb{Z} @>1 + 2n>> \mathbb{Z}/4 @>1>> \mathbb{Z}/4
\\ @VV2V @VV4V @VVV
\\ \mathbb{Z}/4 @>2>> \mathbb{Z}/8 @>>> 0
\end{CD} $$

where $n$ encodes the choice of chain homotopy and on homology groups, the top row does not compose to zero for any choice of $n$.

---

The fix is to redefine "naive complex" to include the parallel zeroes: i.e. so that the index 1-category is a sequence of parallel pairs of arrows such that each arrow coequalizes the pair before it.

(the second arrow in each pair is still required to be zero!)

I interpret Pavlov's comment above as saying that this redefinition of "naive complex" results in a category of complexes that is equivalent to simplicial objects, although I have not proved that myself.

Comment: I don't understand the last part. Some $d$ coequalizes $(d',0)$ if and only if $dd'=0$, so how does this differ from your original version?

Comment: @მამუკაჯიბლაძე: I asked my question because I hadn't appreciated the difference either! I don't yet have a good intuition yet, but mechanically the difference is that it's an equation in the index category, so a functor introduce more equivalences than I had originally. That the iterative calculation works out follows from [this procedure involving Kan extensions](https://mathoverflow.net/a/287049/13113) (expressed there for limits rather than colimits). Or I could be making errors someplace.

Comment: But how do you avoid conditions *outside* the index category? Don't you need to require that either some morphisms forcibly go to zero morphisms, or some object forcibly goes to the zero object?

Comment: @მამუკაჯიბლაძე: Yes; I'm assuming the new arrows all map to zero. Realization by way of iterated coequalizers doesn't actually require the new arrows to be zero; the point is to normalize a degree of freedom (since you can add the same map to both arrows of a parallel pair and get a new diagram satisfying the coequalizer condition and with the same realization). I'm not certain if it's enough to simply require each of the new arrows to be zero or if I need an additional constraint on the entire sequence of new arrows.

Comment: @მამუკაჯიბლაძე: There is actually another diagram I've considered that the iterated cofiber construction works for, depicted below. Maybe this alternate diagram is better behaved; I think it can be seen as a subdiagram of the "upper triangular array" version of complex I mentioned in the OP. $$ \begin{matrix} A_n &\to& A_{n-1}  &\to& A_{n-2} 
\\ & \nearrow \!\!\!\!\!\! \searrow & & \nearrow \!\!\!\!\!\! \searrow 
\\ 0 &\to& 0 &\to& 0
\end{matrix}
$$